# SQLite and BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL

Tags: c++, sqlite

Why does the SQLite C interface requires to pass the pointer by the reference when using `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL`, for example?

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>

#include <sqlite3.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  sqlite3* db;
  BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(db)
  {
    if (sqlite3_close(db) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    }
  };

  if (sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db) != SQLITE_OK)
  {
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  sqlite3_stmt* prepared_stmt = NULL;
  BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(db, prepared_stmt)
  {
    if (sqlite3_finalize(prepared_stmt) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
      std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    }
  };
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(bar TEXT, baz TEXT)", -1, &prepared_stmt, 0) != SQLITE_OK)
  {
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (sqlite3_step(prepared_stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
  {
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

It crashes when trying to call `sqlite3_close` function and doesn't print anything to the stderr. However, if I change

```
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(db)
```

to

```
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(&db)
```

it states that

> unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups

when trying to call `sqlite3_close` function.

If I pass the `prepared_stmt` by the reference too, it works as expected:

```
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(db, &prepared_stmt)
```

Why? I thought that the SQLite library only complains about the addresses that `db` and `prepared_stmt` points to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little perplexed -- why would you call sqlite3_close() on a db before it was ever opened?   I'm just not sure I see the reasoning for that block of code as the first thing in a main() function.   Am I missing something?

Comment: @Amadeus https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html -- "Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle should be released by passing it to sqlite3_close() when it is no longer required"

Answer (score 1):

The first line in main()

```
sqlite3* db;
```

is probably why sqlite3_close() is crashing.   Your compiler may be reusing a memory location for that declared pointer and may not necessarily be using a location that is null or making it null.   Therefore, the call to sqlite3_close() is receiving a bogus pointer.

The docs at https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html state:

> The C parameter to sqlite3_close(C) and sqlite3_close_v2(C) must be
>   either a NULL pointer or an sqlite3 object pointer obtained from
>   sqlite3_open(), sqlite3_open16(), or sqlite3_open_v2(), and not
>   previously closed. Calling sqlite3_close() or sqlite3_close_v2() with
>   a NULL pointer argument is a harmless no-op.

So, according to the above statement, the following code should remove the crash:

```
 sqlite3* db = nullptr;
```

Of course, all of this would be moot if you just removed this block of unecessary code entirely:

```
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(db)
{
  if (sqlite3_close(db) != SQLITE_OK)
  {
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
  }
};
```

There is no reason to close a db that has never been opened.

---

EDIT:  Here is a version of your function as I would try it.  I'm really out of time right now so I can't test it, but I think it will work.   I removed the boost macros since I'm unfamiliar with them, but you could add those back in.    Hopefully this helps!

```
int main()
{
sqlite3* db = nullptr;

if (sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db) != SQLITE_OK)
    goto ERROR_OCCURRED;

sqlite3_stmt* prepared_stmt = nullptr;
if (sqlite3_finalize(prepared_stmt) != SQLITE_OK)
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(bar TEXT, baz TEXT)", -1, &prepared_stmt, 0) != SQLITE_OK)
    goto ERROR_OCCURRED;

if (sqlite3_step(prepared_stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
    goto ERROR_OCCURRED;

if (sqlite3_close(db) != SQLITE_OK)
{   
     std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
     sqlite3_close(db);
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
return 0;

ERROR_OCCURRED:
    std::cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << '\n';
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm out-of-time to check your call to sqlite3_finalize() but I also think that it's probably too early in the function.  I don't see a reason to finalize a null pointer.

Comment: "must be either a NULL pointer or an sqlite3 object pointer obtained from sqlite3_open()" -- in my case `sqlite3_open` returns `SQLITE_OK`. What's wrong then?

Comment: You're calling sqlite3_close() [line 13] before you're calling sqlite3_open() [line 19].    That whole sqlite3_close() block (that I copied in my answer) should probably go at the end of main(), not the beginning.

Comment: Actually, this instance might be a good opportunity to use 'goto'.   Instead of "return EXIT_FAILURE" use "goto LABEL" and then have that label at the end return your EXIT_FAILURE and close the db.

Comment: I updated my answer with an untested version of the function using the concepts I mentioned.   I'm no sqlite3 expert, but I'm fairly sure that this would get the results you're wanting.